# Python Selenium ChromeDriver error message: EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running ChromeDriver 2.34.522940 and Selenium 3.8.0 on Windows 7 and Python 3.6.

I'm trying this code:

```
def foo(url, login, password):
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
```

And it gave the error message:

> DevTools listening on
>   ws://127.0.0.1:12355/devtools/browser/ed317bfa-b264-4fd7-bc5d-aeab717fdb58
>
> [1229/152519.688:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(772)] eglInitialize D3D11
>   failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying next display type

Kept running the following code:

```
    u = driver.find_element_by_name('login')
    u.send_keys(login)
    p = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
    p.send_keys(password)
    p.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

And it gave an new error message:

> [9152:11284:1229/152703.260:ERROR:service_manager.cc(157)] Connection
>   InterfaceProviderSpec prevented service: content_renderer from binding
>   inter face: blink::mojom::ReportingServiceProxy exposed by:
>   content_browser

And a few seconds later:

> [9152:11284:1229/152720.000:ERROR:process_metrics.cc(105)] NOT
>   IMPLEMENTED [9152:11284:1229/152720.000:ERROR:process_metrics.cc(105)]
>   NOT IMPLEMENTED
>   [9152:11284:1229/152720.000:ERROR:process_metrics.cc(105)] NOT
>   IMPLEMENTED [9152:11284:1229/152720.000:ERROR:process_metrics.cc(105)]
>   NOT IMPLEMENTED

I ran the same code yesterday and it didn't give these error messages. What caused these, and how to suppress these error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem got solved by updating to the latest version of ChromeDriver 2.35

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.35/