# Error while opening link using python and selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to open google in browser using python and selenium, gave me following errors:([Image of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nH7P4.png))

> DevTools listening on
>   ws://127.0.0.1:57033/devtools/browser/45f6818b-0d1e-4b81-9
>   637-861b579c7470 [0901/085753.496:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(863)]
>   eglInitialize D3D9 failed with er ror EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
>   [0901/085753.496:ERROR:gl_initializer_win.cc(232)]
>   GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOf f failed.
>   [0901/085753.502:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(201)] Exiting GPU process due
>   to errors during initialization
>   [7188:10216:0901/085753.819:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1016)]
>   Lost U I shared context.
>   [0901/085753.912:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(113)]
>   ContextResult::kFatalF ailure: Shared memory handle is not valid
>   [0901/085753.962:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(113)]
>   ContextResult::kFatalF ailure: Shared memory handle is not valid

It starts chrome browser, also opens the link, but it is giving error in back...

```
print("Starting...")

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

print("Opening...")
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://google.com')
```

Comment: Grass, it will be more useful to you and readers if you write the errors in the question instead of the image...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48028782/1735215). There, the solution was to update to ChromeDriver 2.35. What ChromeDriver version are you using?

Comment: I am running latest `chromedriver`, latest `selenium` and latest `chrome browser`

Comment: webdriver.chrome() needs the path of the driver exe as param..so how are you even able to the browser..

Comment: @SarthakNegi `chromedriver` is in the same folder where my script is there....

Comment: Also, I tried `webdriver.C
hrome('C:\Python\Scripts\chromedriver.exe)`, `webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')`, `webdriver.Chrome('D:\myprojects\chromedriver.exe')` as my **script file is located at "D:\myprojects"** then also it **returned same error**....

Comment: Any updates @SarthakNegi

Comment: @Grass use this - `webdriver.Chrome(r'D:\myprojects\chromedriver.exe')`

Comment: @ShivamMishra then also it is giving  me the same error...

Comment: The problem may be that no one can reproduce the error. On Linux, the code works fine with or without giving the path to chromedriver explicitly. Maybe we need to see more output to see where it is going wrong. You may be able to generate more output with `webdriver.Chrome(service_args=["--verbose", "--log-path=D:\\myprojects\logfile.log"])`, or, if you want to state the path to the executable explicitly: `webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\\myprojects\chromedriver.exe", service_args=["--verbose", "--log-path=D:\\myprojects\logfile.log"])`

Comment: Have a look at [this image](https://imgur.com/Farpl4S), @0range . Error came when I tried, `driver = webdriver.Chrome(service_args=["--verbose", "--log-path=D:\\myprojects\logfile.log"])`

Comment: @Grass Can you also post the log file?