# Only one file type to be accepted

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, filedialog

```
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

filename = fd.askopenfilename(title = "Select file",filetypes = (("CSV Files","*.csv"),("All","*.*")))
```

**Opens the folder to choose the file, but when I try:**

```
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

filename = fd.askopenfilename(title = "Select file",filetypes = ("CSV Files","*.csv"))
```

**Error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:\python_projects\csv_codes\csv_reading.py", line 4, in 
>       filename = fd.askopenfilename(title = "Select file",filetypes = ("CSV Files" ,"*.csv"))   File "C:\Python\lib\tkinter\filedialog.py",
>   line 375, in askopenfilename
>       return Open(**options).show()   File "C:\Python\lib\tkinter\commondialog.py", line 43, in show
>       s = w.tk.call(self.command, *w._options(self.options))
>   _tkinter.TclError: bad file type "*.csv", should be "typeName {extension ?extens ions ...?} ?{macType ?macTypes ...?}?"

**What exactly I want?:**

I want only `.CSV` files to be selected. (compulsory)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`filetypes` needs to be a tuple of tuples. For example:

```
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

filename = fd.askopenfilename(title = "Select file",filetypes = (("CSV Files","*.csv"),))
```

But I suggest you make it all neat and in one window. For example, same input as yours but tidier:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

def get_file_name(file_entry):
    file_name = fd.askopenfilename(title = "Select file",filetypes = (("CSV Files","*.csv"),))
    file_entry.delete(0,END)
    file_entry.insert(0,file_name)

def run_and_close(event=None):
    ######################################
    ## EXECUTE OR CALL OTHER PYTHON FILE##
    ######################################
    close()

def close(event=None):
    master.withdraw() # if you want to bring it back
    sys.exit() # if you want to exit the entire thing

master = Tk()
master.title("This is my Interface")

entry_csv=Entry(master, text="", width=50)
entry_csv.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W, padx=5)

Label(master, text="Input CSV").grid(row=0, column=0 ,sticky=W)
Button(master, text="Browse...", width=10, command=lambda:get_file_name(entry_csv)).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)

Button(master, text="Ok",     command=run_and_close, width=10).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=E, padx=5)
Button(master, text="Cancel", command=close, width=10).grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W)

master.bind('<Return>', run_and_close)
master.bind('<Escape>', close)
mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you please also help me at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52121506/error-while-opening-link-using-python-and-selenium

Comment: @Grass sorry I am not knowledgeable with selenium.