# Browsing file and getting filepath in entrybox in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, openfiledialog, filedialog

I am trying to make a simple GUI using Tkinter in python2, in which I need to make an entry box and a button besides that. The button browses the file and shows the filepath in the entrybox. How can I do that.

I used the `tkFileDialog.askopenfilename` that allows to browse the path but how can I make the gui to show that path in an entry box.

I tried it as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkFileDialog

root=tk.Tk()
def browsefunc():
    filename =tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("tiff files","*.tiff"),("All files","*.*")))

ent1=tk.Entry(frame,font=40)
ent1.grid(row=2,column=2)

b1=tk.Button(frame,text="DEM",font=40,command=browsefunc)
b1.grid(row=2,column=4)

root.mainloop()
```

Attached a screenshot of what I needs.
[image: Attached is the screenshot for desired GUI]

Comment: Just insert the result into `Entry`? What problem are you facing?

Comment: How do I insert the result into the entrybox?

Comment: You can read up methods available for `Entry` widget [here](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you really sure, that you are using python2? Because you wrote `tkinter` with a lowercase `t` and not with an uppercase `T` or did you just write it wrong?.

Anyway, you can easily insert a little text (in your case a path) into your Entry-widget by using the insert method of the Entry-widget. In your case it would be:

```py
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFileDialog

root=tk.Tk()    

ent1=tk.Entry(root,font=40)
ent1.grid(row=2,column=2)

def browsefunc():
    filename =tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("tiff files","*.tiff"),("All files","*.*")))
    ent1.insert(tk.END, filename) # add this

b1=tk.Button(root,text="DEM",font=40,command=browsefunc)
b1.grid(row=2,column=4)

root.mainloop()
```

The `tk.END` parameter gives the last index of the entry-string back. 
If you already wrote something into the Entry-Widget like that:

```py
This is my path:
```

and you add your path, than it will looks like that:

```py
This is my path:/usr/bin/...
```

As you can see it adds the string in the end of the "entry-string". 
The other option would be `0` for the index than your path will be in the beginning of the entry-widget:

```py
/usr/bin...HI
```

I'm sorry if my english is horrible! Feel free to edit it!

Comment: Thanks it worked, But I want the entry button to take new filepath after pressing the button again. It just adds the paths when pressed multiple times. How to get that?

Comment: just write this line over `ent1.insert(tk.END, filename`: 
```python
ent1.delete(0, tk.END)
```
It will clear the entry-widget from beginning (0) till the end (tk.END) of the entry-string.

Comment: Technically `tk.END` doesn't return the last index of the entry string. If you execute `print(tk.END)` it will just output the string `end`. The underlying tk framework knows that you mean the end of the string.

Comment: what should I type in `filetype` if I want to take user input of directory's path?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Doesn't the program put the path into the entry or what exactly do you mean?

Comment: When I specify `filetypes=(("tiff files","*.tiff"),("All files","*.*"))`, it takes files either `.tif` extension or any file. But I want it to select a directory path but not a file. how can I make it do that?

Comment: Probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295917/how-to-select-a-directory-and-store-the-location-using-tkinter-in-python

Comment: and when I type`filetypes=(("tiff files","*.tif"))` only, it gives error, why?

Comment: I just got the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52183821/only-one-file-type-to-be-accepted thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

May be try this code it might work

```
   from tkinter import *
   from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
   root=Tk()

   ent1=Entry(root,font=40)
   ent1.grid(row=2,column=2)

   def browsefunc():
      filename = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("jpg file", "*.jpg"), ("png file 
      ",'*.png'), ("All files", "*.*"),))
      ent1.insert(END, filename) # add this

      b1=Button(root,text="DEM",font=40,command=browsefunc)
      b1.grid(row=2,column=4)

   root.mainloop()
```