# Protractor-selenium error message : "gl_surface_egl.cc eglInitialize D3D9 failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED"

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I am using protractor to test a web application.

I have encountered an error message from cmd saying:

**ERROR : gl_surface_egl.cc(953) eglInitialize D3D9 failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED**

I am guessing the error may have raised due to version mismatch of chrome driver.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
ERROR : gl_surface_egl.cc(953) eglInitialize D3D9 failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
```

...implies that there was an error with **GPU decoding**.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using.

As you are using **ChromeDriver** and **Chrome Browser** you must ensure that the binaries are compatible as per the entries below:

- *ChromeDriver v2.27* : Supports Chrome v54-56
- *ChromeDriver v2.28* : Supports Chrome v55-57
- *ChromeDriver v2.29* : Supports Chrome v56-58
- *ChromeDriver v2.30* : Supports Chrome v58-60
- *ChromeDriver v2.31* : Supports Chrome v58-60
- *ChromeDriver v2.32* : Supports Chrome v59-61
- *ChromeDriver v2.33* : Supports Chrome v60-62
- *ChromeDriver v2.34* : Supports Chrome v61-63
- *ChromeDriver v2.35* : Supports Chrome v62-64
- *ChromeDriver v2.36* : Supports Chrome v63-65
- *ChromeDriver v2.37* : Supports Chrome v64-66
- *ChromeDriver v2.38* : Supports Chrome v65-67
- *ChromeDriver v2.39* : Supports Chrome v66-68
- *ChromeDriver v2.40* : Supports Chrome v66-68
- *ChromeDriver v2.41* : Supports Chrome v67-69
- *ChromeDriver v2.42* : Supports Chrome v68-70
- *ChromeDriver v2.43* : Supports Chrome v69-71
- *ChromeDriver v2.44* : Supports Chrome v69-71
- *ChromeDriver v2.43* : Supports Chrome v69-71
- *ChromeDriver v2.45* : Supports Chrome v70-72
- *ChromeDriver v2.46* : Supports Chrome v71-73
- *ChromeDriver v73* : Supports Chrome v73
- *ChromeDriver v74* : Supports Chrome v74
- *ChromeDriver v75* : Supports Chrome v75
- *ChromeDriver v76* : Supports Chrome v76
- *ChromeDriver v77* : Supports Chrome v77
- *ChromeDriver v78* : Supports Chrome v78
- *ChromeDriver v79* : Supports Chrome v79
- *ChromeDriver v80* : Supports Chrome v80
- *ChromeDriver v81* : Supports Chrome v81
- *ChromeDriver v83* : Supports Chrome v83
- *ChromeDriver v84* : Supports Chrome v84

---

### References

- [Hardware Acceleration doesn't work on Chrome anymore. (AMD Xpress 1250)](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=533043)
- [Python Selenium ChromeDriver error message: EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48028782/python-selenium-chromedriver-error-message-egl-not-initialized)