# Chromedriver selenium opens page but closes 2 seconds later (Multiple Error Messages)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently using chromedriver 2.25 to launch a webpage. Everything is done in python but however, when i run the script, i get the following error below.

my chrome version is chrome 54+ and I'm running windows 7 professional.

I've tried using chromedriver 2.27 but I still get the same error message. Does anyone know why I keep getting this error message :/? Would really apperciate any help here :)

```
   [0131/143630:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(33)] ANGLE Display::initialize 
   error 4 : Could not create D3D11 device.

   [0131/143630:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(612)] eglInitialize D3D11 failed 
   with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying next display type

   [0131/143630:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(33)] ANGLE Display::initialize 
   error 4 : Renderer does not support PS 3.0.aborting!

   [0131/143630:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(612)] eglInitialize D3D9 failed 
   with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED

   [0131/143630:ERROR:gl_initializer_win.cc(272)] 
   GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
   [0131/143630:ERROR:gpu_child_thread.cc(352)] Exiting GPU process due to 
   errors during initialization
   [4632:5396:0131/143630:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(113)] 
   Failed to launch GPU process.
```

This is how I start my driver in python

```
options = Options()
# options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
#options.add_argument('--window-position=10000,10000')
chrome_driver = os.getcwd() +"\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver, chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: I am not completely sure, but this seems like an installation issue.  Your driver may be out of date.

Comment: @Sid I think chromedriver 2.25 is compatible with chrome version 54 though :/

Comment: Another hint is the `GPU` part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that you have reached at the end of your program... It's as simple as that.. Try to use `time.sleep(100)` to wait 100 seconds before terminating your program. Put it at the last line in your script like so:

```
import time

#----- YOU CODE -----
options = Options()
# options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
#options.add_argument('--window-position=10000,10000')
chrome_driver = os.getcwd() +"\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver, chrome_options=options)
#...
#...
time.sleep(100) #waits 100 seconds
```

Comment: I do have other codes running at the bottom of the script but it's mainly getting user's input but the script just crashes before that

Comment: Try to comment the rest of the code, and try this solution and tell me what happens

Comment: The webpage does appear with the same error message, however, it crashes after that

Comment: omg thank you for your help, i just noticed there was a little bug with my code after i added the time.sleep. This has helped me solve the issue. Thank you! :)

Comment: Gald,I could help

Comment: `time.sleep(100)` is not an ideal solution rather covering up the real issue.

Comment: @DebanjanB Actually, you are right, he can use `os.system("pause")` but it only works for windows. He can also use `input()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try  adding this argument `--use-gl=desktop`:

```
options = Options()
# options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--use-gl=desktop')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
#options.add_argument('--window-position=10000,10000')
chrome_driver = os.getcwd() +"\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver, chrome_options=options)
```

If this does not work update your chromedriver to at least `v2.27`.

To see the compatibility list of chromedrivers to  Chrome Browser see [@DebanjanB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7429447/debanjanb)'s [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53389256/8179099).

Hope this helps you!