# ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(750)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: No available renderers error using ChromeDriver and Chrome with Selenium

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to execute basic python google chrome automation selenium command
I am getting below error while executing the below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path=r"xxxx\chromedriver_win32_2\chromedriver.exe"
driver= webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("<somesite>")
```

> Note:
>   I have windows7 64 bit OS, Chrome driver version is latest and chome browser as well latest.

ERROR:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12592/devtools/browser/78ac717d-857a-436c-9b28-ee18bc18fa66
[0615/004254.120:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(750)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: No available renderers.
[0615/004254.127:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1236)] eglInitialize D3D11 failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying next display type
[0615/004255.175:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(750)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: No available renderers.
[0615/004255.176:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1236)] eglInitialize D3D9 failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
[0615/004255.178:ERROR:gl_initializer_win.cc(196)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
[0615/004255.184:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(152)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
Code executing....
[0615/005841.064:ERROR:batching_media_log.cc(38)] MediaEvent: {"error":"MediaSource endOfStream before demuxer initialization completes (before HAVE_METADATA) is treated as an error. This may also occur as consequence of other MediaSource errors before HAVE_METADATA."}
[0615/005942.374:ERROR:batching_media_log.cc(38)] MediaEvent: {"
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
[0615/004254.120:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(750)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: No available renderers
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

This error is generally observed due to mismatch between [selenium-chromedriver](/questions/tagged/selenium-chromedriver) and [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) versions.

---

### Solution

You need to upgrade [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091121/why-doesnt-chromedriver-require-chrome-or-chromium/51096327#51096327) and *Google Chrome* version either to the latest version or to either of the compatible versions as detailed out in the discussion [Protractor-selenium error message : “gl_surface_egl.cc eglInitialize D3D9 failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53387000/protractor-selenium-error-message-gl-surface-egl-cc-eglinitialize-d3d9-failed/53389256#53389256)

---

### Outro

You can find a relevant discussion in:

- [Issue 533043: Hardware Acceleration doesn't work on Chrome anymore. (AMD Xpress 1250)](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=533043)

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB,
thanks for the reply. But i have already tried upgrading to latest version for both even i tried downgrading to same version, before posting this question.
I am left with no cue why its hapennin